# Kubernetes deployment without a port

Tags: kubernetes

I have a service which is long-running (in a `while 1` loop) and processes payloads via GCloud pub/sub, after which it writes the result to a DB.

The service doesn't need to listen on any port.

**What would the declarative YAML config look like for `Kind=Deployment`?**

I understand `ClusterIP` is the default type, and the docs [go on to say](https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/service/#headless-services) that a headless service just has to define `spec.clusterIP` as `None`.

(A better practice would probably be to modify the worker to exit after a successful payload processing, and change the `Kind` to `Job`, but this is in the backlog)

Comment: For `Deployment`, just not specifying `ports` seems to do the trick.

Comment: What exactly is the problem you're trying to solve? It sounds like you just want a deployment to run and initiate outgoing connections without the need for a service at all.

Answer (score 7):

What you're describing sounds more like a job or a deployment than a service. You can run a deployment (which creates a replicaset, which ensures a certain number of replicas are running) without creating a service.

If your pod isn't exposing any network services for others to consume, there's very little reason to create a service.

Comment: Thanks. I mentioned `Kind=Deployment` in the question but will update the question title to be clearer too.